# IS NOT NULL AS ... - Convert Query from MySQL to MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that is working fine using a MySQL/MariaDB-Database.
I did make it more flexible and now I am basically able to use a Microsoft SQL-Server database.

I found out, that some SQL-queries do NOT work anymore.
I don't have experience with MS-SQL and I am looking for support to convert the following query to make it work with MS-SQL. It would be great, if the query could be converted to work in both MS-SQL and MySQL ...

I have created an SQL-Fiddle with some example-data.
Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5fb718/2

The Query itself looks like this:

```
SELECT computermapping.PrinterGUID, computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
FROM computermapping 
LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter ON computerdefaultprinter.ComputerGUID = computermapping.ComputerGUID 
AND computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID = computermapping.PrinterGUID
WHERE computermapping.ComputerGUID = "5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f"
```

When I run this on SQL-Fiddle I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

When I run this Query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I get the same Error. I have an German-Installation ...

> Meldung 156, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 1
> Falsche Syntax in der Nähe des IS-Schlüsselworts.

I was looking on the Internet to find information on how to use the `IS NOT NULL AS` in MS-SQL. Maybe I was using the wrong keywords, but I was not able to find a solution myself.

If it does matter, I am using "SQL-Server 2014 SP3" at the moment.

Thank you

Comment: Each database has its own SQL dialect and MySQL is one of the quirkiest. *ALL* databases are quirky, none follows the SQL standard beyond a basic compatibility level. MySQL is one of the worst offenders, with many common features added in MySQL 8.

Comment: Aside: Try `select 30 / -3 / 5;` in MySql and SQL Server. Not as portable as one might hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert

```
computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL AS isDefaultPrinter
```

to

```
CASE 
   WHEN computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
END AS isDefaultPrinter
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5fb718/4)

Also bear in mind that there is no `BOOLEAN` type in SQL Server. `BIT` type is used instead.

Finally

```
WHERE computermapping.ComputerGUID = "5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f"
```

should be converted to

```
WHERE computermapping.ComputerGUID = '5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f'
```

since the single quote character is used to delimit strings in SQL Server

Comment: Correct, but `WHERE computermapping.ComputerGUID = "5bec3779-b002-46ba-97c4-19158c13001f"` is also an issue. +1

Comment: @Zhorov Yes, this is correct. I've only fixed this in the demo attached, since the OP doesn't mention the issue.

Comment: Wow .. that was fast. I am starting a short test with production data.

Comment: Could you please tell me more about the issue with the WHERE-clause?

Answer (score 2):

MySql evaluates boolean expressions like:

```
computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL
```

as `1` for `TRUE` or `0` for `FALSE`.
SQL Server does not do such an evaluation, so you need a CASE expression:

```
CASE WHEN computerdefaultprinter.PrinterGUID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact question was already answered, but you should really, really try using the [SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/mysql/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-mysql-mysqltosql?view=sql-server-ver15). No database supports the SQL standard beyond a basic compatibility level and MySQL is one of the quirkiest databases when it comes to SQL compatibility.

The SQL standard process is *sloooow* so all vendors implement features long before they're standardized. Different databases have different priorities too, and MySQL's priority for the first decade at least wasn't enterprise applications, so SQL compatibility wasn't a high priority.

Some common features were added only in MySQL 8. Some hacks allowed (but discouraged) in MySQL, like non-aggregate columns in a grouping query, or quirky updates to calculate row numbers, don't work in any other databases because logically, they lead to unpredictable results.

Even in MySQL, non-aggregate columns can cause serious performance degradation when upgrading from one 5.x version to the next. There's at least one SO question about this.

The Migration assistant will convert tables and types where possible and flag any stored procedure or view queries that can't be translated. It can also copy data from an existing MySQL database to a SQL Server database